# How to use Asp.net idenity with .net core and mysql database?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I Created application using asp.net core with mysql database.
Right now, I need to implement authentication and i want to use Asp.net idenity.

But i not able to found any proper integration of asp.net identity with mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use MySQL with Identity in this project : https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle

Read Startup.cs on branche release/1.1.1 if you want a sample with .Net Core 1.1
Use the dev branch for .Net 2.0